# How to make Automator Service using Applescript return text?

Tags: macos, service, automator

I'm trying to write an Automator service that returns some text into the current document, whether it is TextEdit or Pages or Numbers.

I've got the following MWE which compiles and installs properly, and shows up in the Services menu, but when invoked, doesn't actually do anything. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the box for **Output replaces selected text**

It should work whether you have selected any text or not.